# Align text center in bootstrap 'col-md-12'

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text-align

I have a bootstrap designed website and am trying to put a footer at the bottom of each page, I have the following code:

```
<div class ="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class = "col-md-12" >
         <footer style="text-align:center">Company. All Rights Reserved.</footer>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this does not align the text center, what do I have to do to get the text to be in the center of the viewport?

Comment: Works fine here https://www.bootply.com/XdC9ZHZOBH

Comment: use class="text-center" and wrap <div class="row"> with <footer></footer>

Answer (score 0):

In some versions :add `center` Class in `<div class = "col-md-12 center" >`

or

In some versions :add `center-block` Class in `<div class = "col-md-12 center-block" >`

and

for text align center :add `text-center` Class in `<div class = "col-md-12 text-center" >`

[Alignment classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type-alignment)

[Center content blocks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-center)

Comment: class is `text-center` not `center`

Comment: And even once you got the right class, your code is doing what the OP's does anyway, as I noted in my comment and example above

Comment: Thanks all . I added references

Comment: version 3.3.7, @j08691

Comment: @JustinO'Brien Please show me where in Bootstrap 3.3.7 there is a class named `center`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `<div class="col-md-12" >` to `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">`. It helps me.

PS: It might be `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">`

Answer (score -2):

Quick tip:
you missed a `;` at the end of center,
class at the top does not need a space before the `=` , same with the `col-md-12`
too

A better method for your CSS:

```
   <style> 
   footer {
   text-align:center;
   }
   </style>
```

this can also be used in a linked stylesheet.
This method is a better alternative to using inline css, as inline css is much slower to load.

Or you can add the center bootstrap class in your `col-md-12` class as `col-md-12  center`